Load Video on SharePoint Online Immediately
We are facing an issue loading the video on the custom landing page (using AngularJS + HTML) on SharePoint online. It takes 2-3 seconds to buffer the video after loading the page, then it's playing, but we want it to load immediately and play without buffering.
Video is getting fetched from SharePoint Online document library.

You can use the autoplay attribute to make the video start playing as soon as it's ready. Please refer to following code
<video src="path_to_your_video.mp4" preload="auto" autoplay controls></video>

